# Как настроить логи AWS ECS?

Tags: логирование, развертывание, amazon-web-services

Я задеплоил нейронку на ECS, как мне просмотреть поступают ли в нее запросы и как мне отлавливать ошибки, не подключаясь к EC2 через SSH. Вся информация, которую я нашел от AWS, сводится к подключению через ssh к EC2, но ключи, необходимые для подключения по ssh, не создаются, соответственно я не могу использовать ssh.

Comment: «бабушка, дайте воды напиться, а то так кушать хочется, что и переночевать негде». сосредоточьтесь, пожалуйста, на одном вопросе (нажав [edit]). другие несвязанные вопросы надо задавать отдельно. // я бы предложил для начала разобраться с ключами.

Comment: кстати, ssh скорее всего можно использовать. Нужно в security group разрешить inbound traffic на порт 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для мониторинга можно использовать другой сервис AWS: CloudWatch. Для того чтобы начать его использовать, необходимо разрешить роли EC2InstanceProfile(вероятно у вас какое-то свое имя этой роли), которая используется ECS, доступ к CloudWatch и установить CloudWatch Agent в контейнере.

Больше информации здесь: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html